# Калькулятор на Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как правильно запрограмировать данную полоску на Vue?

[image: скрин]

Надо, чтобы при выборе активного input менялась цена.

Comment: Что делает данный компонент? Можете пояснить?

Comment: Дополните вопрос кодом компонента, иначе не очень понятно о чем идет речь.

Answer (score 1):

Если я Вас правильно понял, нужно сделать что-то наподобии мини калькулятора? Набросал шаблончик (только учу vue, больно тапками не кидайте).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      total: 0,
      count: 1,
      packageChecked: 0,
      packages: [
        {
          title: 'Пакет 1',
          price: 500
        },
        {
          title: 'Пакет 2',
          price: 300
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.total = +this.packages[this.packageChecked].price * +this.count;
  },
  computed: {
    totalFormat: function() {
      return this.total + ' руб.';
    }
  },
  watch: {
    packageChecked: function(numberElement) {
      this.total = +this.packages[numberElement].price * +this.count;
    },
    
    count: function(val) {
      this.total = +this.packages[this.packageChecked].price * +val;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#result {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label v-for="(package, packageKey) in packages" :key="packageKey">
    <input 
      type="radio" 
      name="type" 
      :value="packageKey"
      @change="packageChecked = packageKey"
      :checked="packageChecked === packageKey">
    {{ package.title }}
  </label>
  
  <input type="text" v-model="count">
  
  <div id="result">{{ totalFormat }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А я почему-то понял, что `50 руб` стоит пакет, можно выбрать `1 пакет`, `2 пакета` или вбить число, где `+ 3 -`.

Comment: @РустамГимранов а Вы хорош, сколько людей столько и мнений) ждем от автора значит дополнения.

Comment: Да он на комментарии даже не отвечает.